Calculating the density of an image
I have an image file with 100×100 pixel width and height and 96 pixels per inch density. I need to figure out to which value its density should be changed so that if the image will be printed, it will be 2×2 inches.
As far as I understand, the first step is to convert 100 pixels to "screen" inches and then to create an equation. At density 96 ppi, 100 px would be 1.04 in. And here is how I tried to figure out the equation itself:
Step 1. Let's take a look at our images:

Source image  Target image
------------  ------------
96 ppi        ? ppi
1.04 in       2 in

Step 2. So, it seems we need to create the following proportion:

  ?         96
------  =  ----
 1.04       2

Which means that ? = (96 / 2) x 1.04 = 49.92

Step 3. That's it.

49.92 pixels per inch is the correct answer (it can be verified using any online pixels-to-inches calculator), but I don't really understand why this proportion works, why the other proportion I have tried (see below) didn't work, and whether there is a better way than the current one.
 96       ?
----  =  ---
1.04      2

Which means that ? = (96 / 1.04) x 2 = 184.61


You want $100$ pixels to be $2$ inches, which is $\frac{100}{2}=50$ pixels per inch.
In your calculation, you could say $\frac{100}{96}= 1.041666\ldots$ and  $1.041666\ldots\times \frac{96}{2}=50$. This involves $96$s twice, which then cancel, but this is unnecessary.
